# Representing that a Property Is Different from Another Object

Tags: c#, .net

I need to represent that a property on an object is different from that of another datasourace. I have two data sources, and when I pull from one of the datasources, I need a way to determine if any of the properties of the object from that datasource are different from the other datasource.

DSA
  Object1.Value = 3

DSB
  Object1.Value = 4

Obviously, determining that they are different is easy. What i want, however, is the ability to say that DSB.Object1.Value is "different" without needing to also pass the object from DSA to a view.

My initial approach is to have a PropertyWrapper class

```
public class PropertyWrapper<T>
{
    T value;
    bool different;
}
```

Is there a better way to represent this through attributes or extensions?

EDIT: Changed from a "Changed" to a "Different" representation. I don't need real time "changes", instead I need a representation that the property is not the same as the same property of the same object from another data source.

Comment: Better way for what? Performance? Readability? Ease of development?

Comment: That's a very good question. Readability. With this approach I will have a class with 12 PropertyWrapper properties of varying types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you pull it from datasource, the first solution that comes to me is using some inside `boolean` field, say `IsChanged`.

In other words:

The "operator" who operates over that objects should take care of changing a state/field inside it, in order to notify to outside world that something was changed in that object.

There is no easy solution for this, but you can define some generic interface, like `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or invent your own, whom method `SignalChanged` is called on every property `set` function.

Just an idea, there are could be plenty other solutions.

Comment: The IsChanged needs to be represented for each property of an object.

Comment: I would actually change that to store the initial value. That way if it is changed again back to the original, the IsChanged property could return false.

Comment: @Quickhorn: no `IsChanged` is a property of an object. Or if you want to be more accuarte, you can have some List `Changes<propertyName>`, that contains all property values mutated from the last "clear" state.

Comment: @Mat I don't need real time difference notifications. Just a representation that the property is different at the time that I pulled from both data sources.

Comment: @Tigran I am considering a Dictionary of changes Dictionary<string,bool> where the string is the property name. Is this similar to what you're suggesting? There is not going to be an operator of the objects. I pull from both datasources, check the values and determine if things are different. Then pass one of the objects and that representation of what is different up to a controller.

Comment: @Quickhorn: why you need `bool` values ? The poperties inside list are the properties changed, all others wren't changed.

Comment: @Tigran Valid point. Thanks. Thinking about the two approaches, I will likely go with my original approach, but I'm going to mark yours as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Quickhorn: you're welcome. These kind of things usually easier to architect then to actually develop.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that each object implement INotifyPropertyChanged (things like [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver) make this easy) and then some sort of central object could hook up with both instances to determine if they changed after first pulling their values from the data source.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear. I do not need real-time change checking, but a representation that object B has different values (and which values are different) from object A, without also needing object A.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a DateTime timestamp property; updating it with the Current time anytime a change is made.

This has the added benefit of letting you know WHEN a change is made. (which is useful when multiple sources access the data, versioning the data, etc.)

Comment: That is more information than I need. All I need is to know if an object's pulled from one datasource's properties are different than another one, and to store that information.